# Open Source Library for Linguistic Inquiry and Word Count (LIWC)

Tags: java, python, open-source, nlp

I am looking for an open source library for Linguistic Inquiry and Word Count [(LIWC)](http://liwc.net/index.php). Something in java or python will be good, though I am open to use other language.

Does anyone know where I can get one ?

Cheers,

Comment: Are you looking for something which _interfaces_ (not sure how) with LIWC product (from LIWC Inc.) or something which emulates some/all of the features of the LIWC product ?

Comment: I am looking for some/all feature of the LIWC product. Cheers

Comment: The main benefit of the LIWC software is access to the LIWC data, which isn't open source.  There are other word lists that do similar things, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @ealdent what would be alternative word lists? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As **ealdent** points out, LIWC is both software and a data set. The data set is proprietary so there is no open-source version of that. For the software side, [TAWC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tawc/) is a useful open source Perl version. From the comments:

> This is a semi-complicated script adapted from the one used in my CHI
>   papers.  The task of this script is to read in regular expressions from a
>   dictionary (or if they're not REs, to make them into REs), which must be
>   backwards-compatible with the LIWC software set (c.f. 
>   http://www.liwc.net).  It then counts the number of matches for the RE in
>   a single input row / user, and outputs it for that row / user.

You could then buy [LIWClite](http://www.liwc.net/index.php) which is less than half the cost of LIWC. You can also use TAWC with your own dictionaries for free.

Comment: What is the format of the LIWC data? For example, if I buy LIWClite, will I be able to easily use the data from my own program?

Answer (score -7):

You may find the Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) for Python useful: http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: why everyone is downvoting this answer?